# Print stdout and stderr with popen and subprocess in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a script in python that uses subprocess and `comunicate()` but I don't succeed to access to the `stdout` and `stderr`. When I use only the `stdin` the script works well. This is the part of the script:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(["./a.out"],
                        shell=True,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                    )

def inp(self,txt):
    f=open(txt,"r")
    self.proc.communicate(f.read()) #this works well!!

    print self.proc.stdout.read #this doesn't work
    #or
    stdout_value=self.proc.communicate() 
    print stdout_value #this doesn't work
    #self.result.communicate()[1]
```

The same trouble is with the `stderr`. How can I read the output and the `stderr`?

Comment: What happens if you pipe the text file to ./a.out from the terminal? If stderr is very large, you might have a buffering issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), `communicate()` returns the content you are looking for right when it's called. You get it when you replace the second line in your `inp()` method by

```
    stdout_value, stderr_value = self.proc.communicate(f.read())
```

Note: if you expect large amounts of data to be returned `communicate()` is not your best option: the data is buffered in memory, so you might run in trouble there. Instead you'd then better direct your input right to `self.proc.stdin`and then process `self.proc.stdout` in manageable chunks.

Comment: calling `self.proc.wait()` without reading the output may hang the subprocess. There is no issue with `.communicate()` unless the output is larger than available memory.

Answer (score 1):

`.communicate()` waits for the child process to finish. It may be called at most once.

`.communicate()` returns both stdout and stderr as strings if corresponding stdout, stderr parameters are `PIPE`s.

Don't use `shell=True` unless you need it.

You could provide the file as input directly:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

with open(filename, 'rb', 0) as input_file:
    p = Popen(['./a.out'], stdin=input_file, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, err = p.communicate()
```